# Django Image not saving

Tags: django

I am trying to upload an image via the *ImageField*. I am getting http 200, but the image is not getting saved.

My model is:

```
class RestaurantProfile(BaseModel):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    restaurant_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='restaurants', blank=True, null=True)
```

My form is:

```
class UpdateDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-glass', 'id': 'phone',
                                              'placeholder': 'Contact No'}))
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-glass', 'id': 'address',
                                              'placeholder': 'Address'}))
    restaurant_image = forms.ImageField()
```

My view code is:

```
def updatedetails(request):
    current_user = request.user.id
    rest = RestaurantProfile.objects.get(username=current_user)
    rid = rest.id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("fas")
        form = UpdateDetailsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            print(data)
            phone = data["phone"]
            address = data["address"]
            image = data["restaurant_image"]
            RestaurantProfile.objects.filter(id=rid).update(phone=phone, address=address, restaurant_image=request.FILES['restaurant_image'])
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = UpdateDetailsForm()

    return render(request, "updatedetails.html", {'form': form})
```

In my setting.py, I have added:

```
# Media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

In the url.py, I have added:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Does your <form> include the type="multipart/form-data" attribute?

Comment: I have enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need save file manual like this [Django file upload doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/)

or simple way

`form.py`

```
    class UpdateDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
         model = RestaurantProfile
         fields = ('phone', 'address', 'restaurant_image', )
```

`view.py`

```
    form = UpdateDetailsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```